# CakePHP foreach not displaying anything

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

When running my query the foreach loop causes even the HTML not to disply or print out on screen and I cannot find out why...

Here is my Controller:

```
public function signup_complete() {

    $weight=array(
            "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44", 
            "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",
            "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",
            "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",
            "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "44",  "48",  "48",
            "48",  "48",  "52",  "52",  "52",  "52",  "56",  "56",  "56",  "56",
            "60",  "60",  "60",  "60",  "60",  "60",  "60",  "67",  "67",  "67",
            "67",  "67",  "67",  "67",  "67",  "75",  "75",  "75",  "75",  "75",
            "75",  "75",  "82",  "82",  "82",  "82",  "82",  "82",  "82",  "82",
            "90",  "90",  "90",  "90",  "90",  "90",  "90",  "90",  "90",  "90",
            "100", "100", "100", "100", "100", "100", "100", "100", "100", "100",
            "110", "110", "110", "110", "110", "110", "110", "110", "110", "110",
            "110", "110", "110", "110", "110", "125", "125", "125", "125", "125",
            "125", "125", "125", "125", "125", "125", "125", "125", "125", "125",
            "125", "125", "125", "125", "125", "145", "145", "145", "145", "145",
            "145", "145", "145", "145", "145", "145", "145", "145"
    );

    $this->layout='setup';

    $userweight=$this->Auth->user('weight');

    $this->User->bindModel(array('hasOne'=> array('Strengthtable'=> array(
                'className'=>'Strengthtable',
                'foreignKey'=>false
            ))),false);

    $this->set('benchs',$this->User->find('all',array('conditions'=> array(
            'User.id'=>$this->Auth->user('id'),
            'Strengthtable.gender = User.gender',
            'Strengthtable.bench = User.benchmax',
            'Strengthtable.weight'=>$weight[$userweight]
        ))));
}
```

And here is my View:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>username</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>Plan</th>
        <th>Outcome</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php foreach ($benchs as $bench): echo $bench['Strengthtable']['level']; ?>&nbsp;<?php endforeach; ?></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I know this is probably very ugly and inefficient, but this is my first ever time using Cake and i am utterly stumped!

If any additional code is wanted just shout and I will post it

Comment: how does `$benchs` look like?

Comment: do User->find out of this->set and assign to a variable like $arrayUsers = $this->User->find(.... and use debug() function in your controller like debug($arrayUsers) or you can use debug in your view. Paste the result

Comment: I am getting an empty array returned so obviously my query is wrong but I don't know where

Comment: Using the debugger I have it down to these two line are making the array return empty:
'Strengthtable.gender = User.gender',
'Strengthtable.bench = User.benchmax',

Comment: if your have a empty array maybe the query is wrong. You have the echo $this->element('sql_dump'); in your view??? to see the exact query that cake do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your query was wrong you can debug with

```
echo $this->element('sql_dump');
```

in your View.

And see the exact query that cake do.

Then you can compare your expected query with the cake query and modify in your controller the  $this->User->find(...) syntax.